# How to install Czech spell checker for LibreOffice 3.3?

Tags: openoffice, spell-check, i18n, libreoffice

When there was Go-OO everything was simple - just install the application and install all languages you need via language pack installers.

Now, as OOo and LO 3.3 ar out and Go-OO seems to be discontinued (its download site hosts LibreOffice 3.3 now) it seems even simpler (there is one multilanguage installer with all the languages available to choose there) but it is not.

After Installing LibreOffice (Win32) using  all-language installer choosing all the languages I'd like (En-US, En-GB, Ru, Cz, Sk, De, Fr) to have (both for spell checking and as an option for GUI&docs language) I've found that many useless (for me) spelling dictionaries (like African, Norwegian, Estonian, Viet, etc) are available (despite I haven't chosen them in the installer) in the application, but Czech (while Czech GUI is there BTW) and Russian are not (despite I have explicitly chosen to install them).

How to correct this? I can live without Russian dictionary, but Czech is must-have for me.

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice.org site hosts language modules for all languages available.  (Some of them do not qualify to be included into LibreOffice distribution, mostly due to license issues.)

http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/dictionaries